# C# check if a string contains all characters in a list accounting for duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, char, contains

How would one check to see if a string can be made up of the chars in a char list (or array), also accounting for duplicate letters.

So, say I have the string (or char array/list/whatever) "abcc" and the character list (or array/string/whatever, it can all be converted to whatever) "['c'],['b'],['a']". How would one go about checking those two values against each other but also account that 'c' exists only once in the char array and therefore it should fail.

I know I could easily do this with either ".Contains" and run through the entire array of chars deleting that certain character from the array as I go, or use "IndexOf" and do the same thing, but I'd like to know if there's any way to not delete any items from the char array.

Comment: do you mean that `c` exist more than once in the char array and should fail ? vs what you wrote here `How would one go about checking those two values against each other but also account that 'c' exists only once in the char array and therefore it should fail.`

Comment: @MethodMan yeah, I figured my explination would be a little confusing, considering i suck at explaining things. Basically, you have a pool of characters (in this case a char array), and a string. I'd like to be able to check to see if the string can be built from the characters that exist in the pool, which would be simple by checking things like .IndexOf and .Contains, but those don't account for duplicate letters.

Comment: if you know linq you can check for duplicates in a string.. if you know linq you can also check if a string contains duplicates and return a count or the value as well as if a string Contains an array or char..

Comment: @ChristianC there are plenty of excellent tutorials online and MSDN has a free download with all sorts of examples that you can step through and play around with the debugger as well [MSDN 101 LINQ Samples in C#](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = "abbc";
var validChars = new List<char>() { 'c', 'b', 'a' };
var invalidChars = validChars.Where(validChar => input.Count(inputChar => inputChar == validChar) > 1);
```

Then you can check if `invalidChars` has any entries.

Edit: I will leave my original response, but based on your feedback, I think this is the correct procedure to follow.

First, I think it is probably best to convert your character array to some sort of dictionary, with a `char` as the key and an `int` as the value (to tell you how many of that letter you have available).

```
var charPool = new Dictionary<char, int>()
{
   { 'a', 2 },
   { 'b', 5 },
   { 'c', 5 },
   { 'd', 5 },
   { 'f', 0 },
   ...
   { 'z', 5 }
};
```

From there, you can take your input string and apply some LINQ to filter the values based on a criteria. I have chosen `!charPool.ContainsKey(inputChar)` OR `charPool[inputChar] < inputWord.Count(c => c == inputChar)` as my match criteria. These basically state "for each character that this filter is applied to, if 1. the key does not exist in the dictionary, or 2. the value, or number of that char in the dictionary, is less than the occurrences of that char in the input string, then that char is invalid.

Given an input string of

```
var inputWord = "bananafone";
```

The following code should return an IEnumerable of the letters `a`, `f`, and `e`. `a`, because we need 3 and only have 2; `f`, because our entry is at 0 and we need 1; and `e`, because no entry exists for that letter. Also, a `.Distinct()` is used because without it, for this example, `a` would get entered 3 times as iterates through the input string, applying the filter.

```
var charsNeeded = inputWord.Where(inputChar => !charPool.ContainsKey(inputChar) || charPool[inputChar] < inputWord.Count(c => c == inputChar)).Distinct();
```

Note that one downside of this approach is that we do not count the difference between how many characters we have, and how many we need. However I don't think it would be very difficult to implement; you could easily create another dictionary for the input string, for example, and then compare the two.

Comment: I want to like your answer, but man I don't know Linq anywhere near that well.

Comment: Perhaps I can walk you through it. Quick question though--is your character array unique? If the array has e.g. two 'b's, does the string need to have exactly two bs?

Comment: so think something like scrabble for example. 
If you have the letters "e,c,c,h,k,o,n", then you can make the words "cone", "echo" or "check". so the string doesnt need to use up all of the letters for example, but it cannot use letters that don't exist.

Comment: this answer is so close, so i'll give you accepted answer, even though its not exactly there, I'll probably be able to use it to do what I want.

Comment: One moment, I will update my post with some changes.

Comment: i think you've earned your Accepted answer, thanks for all the help. youve sparked a want to learn Linq better.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps! LINQ is very straightforward once you play with it a little bit. For the `where` example, just think of it as applying a 'filter' (some boolean statement(s)) to a list that returns values that meet your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with large lists of characters and if they will all be ASCII characters, then to keep it efficient I'd think about going through the two strings and counting how often each character appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Using your Scrabble comment, how about this: Get the total count of each character in your input and compare that to the count of the same character in your allowed character list. If the input string ever contains more of a character than the allowed character list does, the input string isn't valid.

```
private static bool ValidateString(string input)
    {
        bool retValue = true;
        char[] validChars = { 'a', 'b', 'd' };
        foreach (var character in input)
        {
            //count the number of times the character occurs in the input string
            var characterCount = input.Count(c => c == character);
            //count the number of times the character occurs in the allowed char array
            var allowedCharacterCount = validChars.Count(c => c == character);
            //if the string contains more than the character array allows, immediately fail.
            if (characterCount > allowedCharacterCount)
            {
                retValue = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        return retValue;

    }
```

This probably isn't the most efficient way to do things, especially if the string is valid, since it goes through the entire string character by character.  But I think it's functional.

Comment: this is actually very nice, but in the end, i do think I'll be going with just looping through, and deleting the letters used. ie:
`foreach( char c in candidate)
 {
   if (availableLetters.IndexOf(c) != -1)
      availableLetters.RemoveAt(availableLetters.IndexOf(c));
 }`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could go about this by creating a tally of each of the letters in the string by converting to a char array and if your case you would have 3 ints (a,b,c)or an int array with (0-25) where a=1 b=1 and c=2 then compare by doing the same thing with the other array and saying if the array your checking against the strings a value is >= to the one of the strings a value then you're good and you can move on to checking b until the point you check to see whether your c value 2 is >= to the other value of c=1 and you get false so it stops.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your search list (that is, the list of characters you're searching FOR in the target string) be an array or list of objects rather than just characters. Then you can have a boolean associated with each character to indicate "IsFoundInTarget" - that way you can "mark" each character without deleting it.  Lastly, do a `.Find(x=> x.Character == TheCharacterBeingSearchedFor && x.IsFoundInTarget == False)` or something similar to handle multiple occurrences of a character.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is not that difficult to understand you can break this down into two steps if you like

1st

```
//Check to see if the input values exist in the collection
var input = "abbc";
var collection = new List<char>() { 'c', 'b', 'a' };
bool doesContain = collection.Any(item => input.Contains((char)item));
```

doesContain will return true

2nd

```
//check for duplicates in the input variable
var duplicatesList = input.GroupBy(s => s)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1)).ToList();
```

using the debugger it will return `b`

Answer (score 0):

We can use default method **contains** 
var str="Ramesh";
str.contains("s").Count();